# Need help factoring polynomial expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I've started reading through a pre-calculus textbook for self-study and came across this problem in the second chapter:
$$(x-2)^3-(x-2)^2$$
 The final answer is $(x-2)^2(x-3)$

Everywhere I look but I have no idea how it comes to that. Binomial expansion was mentioned on one site but the binomial theorem appears in a later chapter. What is the method/methods used to factor this expression?

Comment: Let $\ y = x\!-\!2.\ $ Then it is $\ y^3 - y^2 = y^2(y - 1) = (x\!-\!2)^2 (x\!-\!2 - 1)\ \ $

Answer (score 5):

Use the distributive property:
$$ab-ac=a(b-c)$$
Here, we have
$$a=(x-2)^2\qquad b=(x-2)\qquad c=1$$
Thus
$$(x-2)^3-(x-2)^2=(x-2)^2((x-2) -1)=(x-2)^2(x-3)$$

Comment: Thank you! Now it makes sense.